# Dynamic TOP N / TOP 100 PERCENT in a single query based on condition

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

A local variable `@V_COUNT` `INT`. If the variable `@V_COUNT` is `'0'`(zero) the return all the records from table otherwise return the number of `{@V_COUNT}` records from table. For example if `@V_COUNT = 50`, return `TOP 50` records. If `@V_COUNT` is `0` then return `TOP 100 PERCENT` records. Can we achieve this in a single query?

Sample query :

```
DECLARE @V_COUNT INT = 0

SELECT  TOP (CASE WHEN @V_COUNT > 0 THEN  @V_COUNT ELSE  100 PERCENT END) *
FROM    MY_TABLE
ORDER BY COL1
```

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'percent'

Comment: what is variable @A ? Bring Percent out of Case statement `SELECT  TOP (CASE WHEN @A = 1 THEN  10 ELSE  100  END) PERCENT *
FROM    MY_TABLE`

Comment: @Ven, sorry , typo, edited.

Comment: Please note that using `top x` without an `order by` clause means your query will return arbitrary x records, making it non-deterministic and unpredictable.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes, i know that , actually this is a sample query to generate the scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to not use `TOP` at all - but [`ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead:

> `SET ROWCOUNT` stops processing after the specified number of rows.
>   ...
>   To return all rows, set `ROWCOUNT` to `0`.

Please note that `ROWCOUNT` is recommended to use only with `select` statements -

> **Important**
>   Using `SET ROWCOUNT` will not affect `DELETE`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE` statements in a future release of SQL Server. Avoid using `SET ROWCOUNT` with `DELETE`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE` statements in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. For a similar behavior, use the `TOP` syntax.

```
DECLARE @V_COUNT INT = 0

SET ROWCOUNT @V_COUNT -- 0 means return all rows...

SELECT   *
FROM    MY_TABLE
ORDER BY COL1

SET ROWCOUNT 0 -- Avoid side effects...
```

This will eliminate the need to know how many rows there are in the table

Be sure to re-set the `ROWCOUNT` back to `0` after the query, to avoid side effects (Good point by Shnugo in the comments).

Comment: Thank you, mine query is little complicated, i can use this method simply in my existing query block without any effort. :)

Comment: Well, besides the fact, that there might be side-effects I try to avoid the need for multi-statement approaches. This approach cannot be used with a VIEW or an iTVF...

Comment: @Shnugo You are correct, of course - but I still think it's a better approach then selecting `count(1)` as well, especially for complicated select statements....

Comment: I just placed an answer myself... As the OP wants to specify `PERCENT` an absolut number might not be enough. This will need some sort of computation too. At the end the OP has accepted yours, so he seems to be happy ;-) Happy Coding!

Comment: @Shnugo good point about the side effects - I've edited that into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 100 percent you can write some very big number, which will surely be bigger than possible number of rows returned by the query, eg. max int which is 2147483647.

Comment: I'd go with this approach, but without the keyword `PERCENT`... It might be a good idea to place some working code (against any system-table)...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
DECLARE @V_COUNT INT = 0

SELECT  TOP (CASE WHEN @V_COUNT > 0 THEN  @V_COUNT ELSE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MY_TABLE) END) *
FROM    MY_TABLE
```

Comment: Please note that for complicated queries containing joins and a where clause, this solution might grow very cumbersome and slow-running.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @V_COUNT int = 3
select * 
from 
  MY_TABLE 
ORDER BY 
Service_Id asc  
offset case when @V_COUNT >0 then  ((select count(*) from MY_TABLE)- @V_COUNT) else @V_COUNT end rows
```

Comment: --u can use offset
--in case statement 
--if count is zero it gives u all records
--else  (count(*))- V_COUNT  gives u top rows of the V_COUNT  

--100 % working Test it

Note
Insead of giving count(*) , give count(any column name) which reduces retrival time

Comment: Please get into the habit of formatting your code. Your answer is very tricky to read. Also, please edit your question to include the explanation in your comment.

Answer (score -1):

`SET ROWCOUNT` forces you into procedural logic. Furthermore, you'll have to provide an absolute number. `PERCENT` would need some kind of computation...

You might try this:

```
DECLARE @Percent FLOAT = 50;

SELECT  TOP (SELECT CAST(CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects) AS FLOAT)/100.0 * CASE WHEN @Percent=0 THEN 100 ELSE @Percent END +1 AS INT))  o.*
FROM    sys.objects o
ORDER BY o.[name];
```

This looks a bit clumsy, but the computation will be done once within microseconds...

Comment: It's not the computation that is the problem it's the fact that the result set to get the count from might take a long time to produce, depending on the actual query. Also, the OP stated that they want to get the specific number of rows, not the present - "otherwise return the number of {@V_COUNT} records from table"

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sure, but if the OP *needs* `PERCENT`, this will happy anyway... If an absolute number is good enough, I'd go with Limonkas answer...

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Ah, sorry, I see what you mean. I've got this wrong. They want the absolute number, but 100% in case of null. In this case Linonkas answer was my favourite...